# Error while trying to connect to Elasticsearch using R

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I'm trying to upload data to `Elasticsearch` using `R`.

I am using elastic package to perform this operation. I've tried passing the proxy settings as well. But I'm still not able to connect to the server.

I'm using the following code:

```
proxy <- use_proxy("http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx",port = xxxx, username = "xxxxx@xxx.com", 
                   password = "xxxxxxxx")
elasticon <- connect(headers = proxy)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> Error in curl::handle_setheaders(opts$url$handle, .list = opts$headers) : 
>     All headers must be strings.

Comment: First, `use_proxy`  is from the httr package. Instead of `httr`, we're using `crul` as the http client inside `elastic`. See `?crul::set_proxy` - I think you should be able to set proxy through that and then it will be used when you do elastic fxn calls - i don't have a way to test it, let me know if it works

Comment: I'm not getting this error: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(x$url$url, handle = x$url$handle) : necessary data rewind wasn't possible

Comment: @sckott Any explanation about the above mentioned error. It would be of great help if you could give me pointers in relation to uploading R datatable to elasticsearch.

Comment: ive never seen that error - a search https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=curl+necessary+data+rewind+wasn%27t+possible shows some possible solutions